# How to make twitter bootstrap subcategory on the right side of the category when mouse hovers over it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to add subcategory on the right side of the category when mouse hovers over it . Here in the code

```html
<div class="col-md-3 column margintop20">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">


  <li><a href="#">Option 1<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span> </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 2<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span> </a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Option 3<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span> </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 4<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span> </a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Option 5<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span> </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to append a drop down on the right side of your Menus?

Comment: yes  that is what i am trying to.

Comment: I have updated my answer with updated JsFiddle. Check it. It might solves your problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the following code to do it. I have already did it in the past and the code is working perfect. I always use the this code to do it.

**EDIT:**

**[Updated JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/4tLny70x/2/)**

You need to use the following CSS.

```
/****  Sub DropDown Menus ****/
 .dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu > a:after {
    display: block;
    content:" ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

And you needs to add the following HTML to each list item in your list and it will show the child items on the right on hover.

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Option 1<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span> </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Child1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child5</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

---

**[Working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/4tLny70x/).**

```css
****  Sub DropDown Menus ****/

.dropdown-submenu
{
    position: relative;
}

    .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu
    {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -6px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu > a:after
    {
        display: block;
        content: " ";
        float: right;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
        border-left-color: #ccc;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: -10px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after
    {
        border-left-color: #fff;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left
    {
        float: none;
    }

        .dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu
        {
            left: -100%;
            margin-left: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
            border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BrandLogo</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home Page <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li id="Configure" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Configure<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">Accounts1</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Option1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option5</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">Accounts2</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Option1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option5</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">Accounts3</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Option1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option5</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```